# Як правильно: "іноземний" чи "закордонний" стосовно речей?

Tags: вибір-слова

Чи існує лаконічне і обґрунтоване правило вибору між словами [*«іноземний»*](http://sum.in.ua/s/inozemnyj) та [*«закордонний»*](http://sum.in.ua/s/zakordonnyj), якщо йдеться про речі, виготовлені в іншій країні?

СУМ вказує, що частіше *«закордонний»* вживається стосовно друкованих видань, але це не виглядає досить слушним.

P.S. Слово [*«зарубіжний»*](http://sum.in.ua/s/zarubizhnyj) прохання не пропонувати; я вважаю його росіянізмом і намагаюся не використовувати.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Приклади із СУМ-11 показують що справді - закордонний стосується будь чого що має відношення до закордону: речі, виготовлені за кордоном; паспорт для виїзду за кордон; представники вітчизняних організацій, що ведуть справи за кордоном.

У той самий час іноземний - це чужинницький, належний до іншої держави: література, мова, армія, уряд; тобто те, що не може стати "нашим" навіть у термінах володіння. Єдиний приклад "Жанна полюбляла.. іноземне ганчір'я" теж ставить слово "іноземний" у негативний контекст, тобто "такий, що нам не властивий".

Стаття у СУМ-20 щодо закордонного майже не змінилася, а щодо іноземного дає такі приклади, де знов один про "елементи чужого життя" (каталоги), або про щось унікальне, що існує в єдиному екземплярі (пляшка горілки):

> *Аж Петро Іванович згадав про пляшку горілки іноземної, яку щедра доня батькам у подарунок дала (Люко Дашвар); Щоразу з поїздки привозив він своїй дружині цілу колекцію іноземних каталогів, у яких можна було побачити усе “багатство” європейської легкої промисловості (із журн.).*

Тобто, айфон іноземного виробництва, який мають багато людей і який може бути придбаний в українських магазинах - це закордонний смартфон, бо має відношення до закордону, але є частиною нашого побуту.

Смартфон, який привезений іноземцем і який є унікальною річчю (а тим більше, якщо ним не можна користуватися в українських мобільних мережах) - це вже іноземний смартфон.

---

У пошуках різниці між словами стикнувся із різницею між "[закордонними інвестиціями](http://epi.cc.ua/pryamyie-zarubejnyie-investitsii.html)" і "іноземними інвестиціями". Гугл використовує їх як синоніми, але "іноземні інвестиції" це кошти іноземних інвесторів вкладені у наші підприємства, а "закордонні інвестиції" - це більш загальне означення коштів, що вкладені підприємством у закордонне підприємство, філію і т.і.

Тобто "закордонні інвестиції США" - кошти, які американські інвестори вклали у закордонні підприємства. А "іноземні інвестиції у США" - це кошти які інвестовані у економіку США.

---

> [ЗАКОРДО́ННИЙ](http://sum.in.ua/s/zakordonnyj), а, е. Стос. до закордону. *Комісар закордонних справ стояв на березі й дивився в синю морську далечінь.. (Юрій Яновський, II, 1958, 108);* 
>   //  Який міститься, живе, здійснюється, видається або виготовляється за кордоном. *Тут глянув на нього з-за річки широкий простір зелених плавнів, замріяли вдалині закордонні села (Михайло Коцюбинський, I, 1955, 188); Ах, якби знали її [Софіїні] закордонні приятельки, серед кого доводиться їй тут жити... (Олесь Гончар, Таврія, 1952, 140)*
>   //  Прибулий або привезений з країн, що знаходяться за кордоном. *Жаль мені, що не буду в Києві та не побачу всіх закордонних гостей (Леся Українка, V, 1956, 278); Це був **старий закордонний трактор**, од якого вимагалося неможливого ... (Юрій Яновський, II, 1954)*

---

> [ІНОЗЕ́МНИЙ](http://sum.in.ua/s/inozemnyj), а, е. Стос. до іншої держави, країни, належний їм; чужоземний, чужинницький. *До цих мертвих і вузьких засад пристосовують вони [гімназичні вчителі] літературу іноземну.. (Іван Франко, XVI, 1955, 106); Знати якусь іноземну мову, німецьку наприклад (Анатолій Шиян, Баланда, 1957, 147); Іноземне військо; Іноземний капітал;* 
>   //  Закордонний. *Жанна полюбляла.. іноземне ганчір'я (Любомир Дмитерко, Наречена, 1959, 182); Іноземна преса.*